# ERROR Failed to execute goal 32morg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, maven-surefire-plugin

I have created DataDriven Maven Based  JAVA Selenium test automation Framework but While Running my project as  Maven Clean test I am getting

MAVEN Build getting Failed with Below Error

```
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m[INFO] [1;31mBUILD FAILURE[m[INFO] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m[INFO] Total time:  15.245 s[INFO] Finished at: 2024-02-25T18:44:02+05:30[INFO] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m[ERROR] Failed to execute goal [32morg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test[m [1m(default-test)[m on project [36mDataDrivenProject[m: [1;31mExecution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process[m[ERROR] [1;31mjava.lang.NullPointerException[m[ERROR] [1;31m at utilities.ScreenshotUtil.captureScreenshot(ScreenshotUtil.java:26)[m[ERROR] [1;31m   at extentlisteners.ExtentListeners.onTestFailure(ExtentListeners.java:57)[m[ERROR] [1;31m   at org.testng.internal.TestListenerHelper.runTestListeners(TestListenerHelper.java:67)[m[ERROR] [1;31m  at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1389)[m[ERROR] [1;31m  at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1042)[m[ERROR] [1;31m at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)[m[ERROR] [1;31m    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)[m[ERROR] [1;31m  at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)[m[ERROR] [1;31m    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)[m[ERROR] [1;31m   at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)[m[ERROR] [1;31m at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)[m[ERROR] [1;31m at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)[m[ERROR] [1;31m  at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)[m[ERROR] [1;31m at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)[m[ERROR] [1;31m at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)[m[ERROR] [1;31m  at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)[m[ERROR] [1;31m    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)[m[ERROR] [1;31m at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)[m[ERROR] [1;31m    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)[m[ERROR] [1;31m  at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:295)[m[ERROR] [1;31m at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:84)[m[ERROR] [1;31m  at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:90)[m[ERROR] [1;31m   at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)[m[ERROR] [1;31m at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)[m[ERROR] [1;31m  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)[m




When I check then it shows that BrowserSession is not getting created . 

Test class: testcases.BankManagerLoginTest

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 122.0.6261.70 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe 
Host info: host: 'DESKTOP-9BA474E', ip: '192.168.113.29'
Build info: version: '4.16.1', revision: '9b4c83354e'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.21'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], extensions: []}}]}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:140)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:96)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:68)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:163)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:200)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:175)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:523)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:237)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:84)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:52)
    at base.BaseTest.setUp(BaseTest.java:186)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at      java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:401)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:295)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:90)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

I tried added code for latest dependecny in MAVEN POM File
POM

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.16.1</version>
    </dependency>


 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
    </dependency>`
```